# Unable to deserialize JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON String which (according to validators) is valid JSON and I am stuck at trying to parse it as object in c#.

Sample String:

```
{"asks":[["49999.99000","20.00000000"],["900.00000","4.00000000"],["100.00000","5.00000000"]],"bids":[["5.40000","15.06500000"],["5.53675","0.50000000"],["5.00000","6.00000000"]]}
```

I have tried to use http://json2csharp.com/ and it suggests this class (which does work):

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<List<string>> asks { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> bids { get; set; }
}
```

However I want to parse it like `List<Ask> asks { get; set; }`. I have tried the following:

```
public class Orderbook
{
    public List<Ask> asks { get; set; }
    public List<Bid> bids { get; set; }
}

public class Ask
{
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
}

public class Bid
{
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
}
```

But this fails with *Type 'namespace.Ask' is not supported for deserialization of an array.*

Comment: Isn't it because you have arrays of strings?

Comment: That's because you're trying to deserialize an array into object. Your JSON for a single 'ask' should be something like `{"amount":1231.321,"price":3123.123}`

Comment: This is the format provided by the service I am querying. I was hoping that it would be possible to easily cast/convert this to the format I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `Ask` and `Bid` classes

```
var orderBook = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Orderbook>(json); //Json.Net
//OR
var orderBook = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Orderbook>(json);  //JavaScriptSerializer

public class Orderbook
{
    public List<List<string>> asks { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> bids { get; set; }
}
```

BTW: values are strings (`"49999.99000"`) not double

**EDIT**

`asks` and `bids` are *Array of arrays*, So converting them to an array of concerete class (during deserialization) would require many tricks( if possible). Why don't you simply iterate on `orderBook` to form what you want ?

```
var asks = orderBook.asks.Select(a => 
                      new Ask { 
                          amount = double.Parse(a[0],CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
                          price = double.Parse(a[1],CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious thing (values are strings), thats something I have overlooked. 
Unfortunateley I cannot change the format as this is a third party output I am using. So what I would need is a way to cast/convert these values to double - is that easily possible?
Forthermore I wanted to stick to the `Ask` and `Bid` as this would allow me easier access to these properties (better than specifying the array index I guess).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Marked as solution as I was able to get it to work this way!